# Can't get Textillate Plugin to work properly

Tags: jquery

Using [Textillate Plugin](https://github.com/jschr/textillate), I've trying to recreate the simple [demo](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/)... however, I'm not sure why I'm unable to get the "OUT" part of the effect working. I want the block of text to fade in from the left and fade out to the right. But I suck and nothing I try seem to work. If anyone has used this plugin, maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Note: When I add effect to the "out" or "in", the plugin doesn't work at all.

```
<div class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li>Hello World!</li>
        <li>I hate you</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$('.tlt').textillate({
       in: {
           shuffle: false,
           sync: true
       },
       out: {
             effect: 'FadeOutRightBig',
             shuffle: false,
             sync: true
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effect names are case sensitive as they correspond to a particular class defined in animate.css.

Change FadeOutRightBig to fadeOutRightBig.

```
$('.tlt').textillate({
   in: {
       shuffle: false,
       sync: true
   },
   out: {
         effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
         shuffle: false,
         sync: true
   },
   loop: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/vzsUd/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Was pulling my hair out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it work fine.try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tlt').textillate({
       in: {
           shuffle: false,
           sync: true
       },
       out: {
             effect: 'FadeOutRightBig',
             shuffle: false,
             sync: true
       }
});

    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li>Hello World!</li>
        <li>I hate you</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. The "In" works fine, but the "OUT" doesn't work at all.

Comment: u checked it with firefox?

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. Thank you @HamedKhosravi.